# CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE in hive runs successfully but gives zero results

Tags: hiveql

When I execute a `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` in hive, it runs successfully but it gives zero results. I use :

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' stored as textfile
LOCATION '/common_folder/nyc_taxi_data/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="2");
```

where data is given in `nyc_taxi_data`. Does this only create a view with no data?

Answer (score 0):

Use LOCATION '/common_folder/nyc_taxi_data' instead of 
LOCATION '/common_folder/nyc_taxi_data/' in your DDL.

If you have already loaded the data in hdfs, test with a select query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file from which the data is being loaded into table is "nyc_taxi_data" use LOCATION '/common_folder/nyc_taxi_data'
If "nyc_taxi_data" is the parent folder use LOCATION '/common_folder/nyc_taxi_data/name_of_the_text_file'